# Python `for` loop doesn't update `numpy` array values

Tags: python, numpy, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a simple numerical gradient function and part of it is a for loop updating parameter values that would later be evaluated. The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np


def target_gradient(theta):
    e = 10

    for i in range(theta.shape[0]):
        theta_upper = theta
        theta_lower = theta
        theta_upper[i] = theta[i] + e
        theta_lower[i] = theta[i] - e
        print(f"theta_upper {theta_upper}")
        print(f"theta_lower {theta_lower}")


    return theta_upper, theta_lower

u, l = target_gradient(np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))
```

However, instead of the anticipated output, I get `[1 1 1 1 1]` for both arrays. Print statements are there for monitoring and they show that throughout the loop the arrays didn't change (i.e. were `[1 1 1 1 1]`).`e=10` is so that the effect is more pronounced. I also tried the `enumerate()` approach, but get the same result.

The full gradient funtion would look something like this

```
def target_gradient(theta, x, y):
    e = 0.01
    gradient = np.zeros(theta.shape[0])

    for i in range(theta.shape[0]):
        theta_upper = theta
        theta_lower = theta
        theta_upper[i] = theta[i] + e
        theta_lower[i] = theta[i] - e

        gradient[i] = (
            foo(theta=theta_upper, x=x, y=y) - foo(theta=theta_lower, x=x, y=y)
        ) / (2 * e)

    return gradient
```

Therefore, I am intentionally declaring `theta_upper = theta` inside the loop because I want to calculate the gradient for which I need partial (numerical) derivatives.

Comment: What is your expected output? If you're simply adding `10` to all elements of `theta`, your function can just be `return theta + 10, theta - 10` because numpy arrays can add scalars elementwise

Comment: In python, `theta_upper = theta` does not make a copy; `theta_upper` is just another name for `theta`.

Comment: @hpaulj so after what I did up there `theta`, `theta_upper` and `theta_lower` were just three variable names pointing to the same location in the memory, correct?

Comment: @cc88 those are three variables referring to the same object, yes. See: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach depends on what `foo` is:

**If `foo` can take vector arguments and return vector values, e.g.**

```
def foo(theta, x, y):
    return x * y * np.sin(theta)
```

Then you can simply do:

```
def target_gradient(theta, x, y, e=0.01):
    foo_upper = foo(theta + e, x, y) # Add e to the entire theta vector, and call foo
    foo_lower = foo(theta - e, x, y) # Subtract e from the entire theta vector, and call foo
    return (foo_upper - foo_lower) / (2 * e)
```

Based on your code, where you pass a vector `theta_upper` to `foo`, I suspect this is the case.

**If `foo` can't take vector arguments and return vector values, e.g.**

```
def foo(theta, x, y):
    return x * y * math.sin(theta)
```

then you need to iterate over `theta`, and call `foo` for each value.

```
def target_gradient(theta, x, y, e=0.01):
    gradient = np.zeros(theta.shape[0])

    for i in range(theta.shape[0]):
        foo_upper = foo(theta[i] + e, x[i], y[i]) # Take a single value of theta, and add e
        foo_lower = foo(theta[i] - e, x[i], y[i]) # Take a single value of theta, and subtract e
        gradient[i] = (foo_upper - foo_lower) / (2 * e)

    return gradient
```

Comment: +1, quite elegant, tho just note that vector solution wouldn't work because it wouldn't produce partial derivatives needed for the gradient. Non-vector solution works.

Comment: @cc88 as I said, it depends on `foo`. In this case I assumed that your function is `x * y * sin(theta)`, where `theta.shape == x.shape == y.shape` and they're all vectors. For example: `thetas = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100); x = np.ones_like(thetas); y = np.ones_like(thetas)` gives the same `target_gradient(thetas, x, y)` for both implementations. Of course, this changes if your function is different

Answer (score -1):

The reason why `theta_upper` and `theta_lower` are not changing inside the loop is because you are creating copies of `theta` and assigning them to `theta_upper` and `theta_lower`. Therefore, when you modify `theta_upper[i]` or `theta_lower[i]`, you are not modifying the original `theta` array.

To fix this, you can use the `copy()` method to create a copy of `theta` that you can modify inside the loop, like this:

```
def target_gradient(theta):
    e = 10

    for i in range(theta.shape[0]):
        theta_upper = theta.copy()
        theta_lower = theta.copy()
        theta_upper[i] = theta[i] + e
        theta_lower[i] = theta[i] - e
        print(f"theta_upper {theta_upper}")
        print(f"theta_lower {theta_lower}")

    return theta_upper, theta_lower
```

Comment: They are _not_ creating copies of `theta`, so `theta_upper` is the same array as `theta_lower`. _You_ are creating copies of `theta`, so those variables are now independent. Also note you probably want to do this _outside_ the loop, because if you do it inside, the resulting arrays will only differ from `theta` at the last index

Comment: Also, please don't add irrelevant text like "let me know if this helps" or "hope this helps". That is implied by the fact that you've posted an answer

Comment: @PranavHosangadi so an array within a loop acts like a local (to the loop) variable? And if I want to declare a separate array in memory I should assign it with `.copy()`?

Comment: @cc88 no, loops do not have their own scope in python. IF you want to create a new object in Python, you must do so explicitly. Using `.copy()` is one way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so g.newt's suggestion is right, even if sloppily explained? (it worked for me btw)

Comment: @cc88 yes. "Sloppily" is being generous. Their explanation is downright wrong, because they have it backwards. It's also not a good way to do what you want, especially so in light of your edit

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Would you mind suggesting an alternative way of doing it? I would give it an answer if you do, obviously.

Comment: @cc88 I already did :) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75487865/843953)

Comment: haha sorry, I was busy and wrote it on the fly. I should've double-checked my solution.